# Animate autolayout constraints on keyboard show and hide

Tags: ios, swift, animation, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

So as to make this short and sweet, I am trying to replicate the layout and animation of the `Facebook` login screen. Here it is:

[image: Facebook login screen]

I'm trying to start simple with the logo. Here is how I have setup my `logoContainerView`:

```
// Logo Container View
logoContainerView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-golf-ball-64"))
logoContainerView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
logoContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
headerContainerView.addSubview(logoContainerView)
// Logo Container AutoLayout
logoContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
logoContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
logoContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerContainerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
logoContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerContainerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Now I'm simply just trying to get the logo to move on the xAxis and adjust the constraint size when the keyboard is shown. I am doing this with the following code:

```
fileprivate func observeKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow() {
    logoContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
    logoContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
    self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

This does actually work. However, I'm receiving what looks to be a `warning` more than an `error`:

```
2018-03-27 11:47:12.392282-0600 My App[4075:156614] [LayoutConstraints] 
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000284380 UIImageView:0x7ffe84d13390.height == 100   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000291df0 UIImageView:0x7ffe84d13390.height == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000284380 UIImageView:0x7ffe84d13390.height == 100   (active)>
```

I am assuming that I am receiving this `warning` because I am trying set `logoContainerView`s `heightAnchor` through making it active when I already previously set this `heightAnchor` and made it active.

My ultimate question would be how to resolve this appropriately? How do I set constraints based on whether the keyboard is showing and when it is not?

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to respond and assist.

Comment: I think you should deactivate your existing constraint before you activate your new constraint

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you currently add constraints to existing ones and this causes a conflict

```
var hCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
var wCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

//

```
self.hCon = logoContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0) 
self.hCon.active = true
self.wCon = logoContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0) 
self.wCon.active = true
```

//

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow() {
   self.hCon.constant = 50 
   self.wCon.constant = 50
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
   }, completion: nil)
}
```